# How do you disable tables in Kramdown?

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown, kramdown

So I recently made the switch from Maruku to Kramdown on Github Pages, and I ran into a problem:

[image: Problem with Kramdown]

Here's the markdown that's causing the problem:

```
Five days ago I wrote [Standardizing Harmony Classes]
(/standardizing-harmony-classes "Aadit M Shah | Standardizing Harmony Classes").
```

You see that pipe in `"Aadit M Shah | Standardizing Harmony Classes"`? Kramdown erroneously treats it as a table cell separator resulting in the horrendous table above, which is actually supposed to be a paragraph.

This makes no sense because the pipe separator is inside a link text literal, and markdown should not be applied to link text literals. Clearly this is a bug in Kramdown.

So how do you disable tables in Kramdown Jekyll? There are lots of places where I have pipes and I don't wish to change them. Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: Apparently this issue is still around. Running into the same issue with an image and its alt text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escaping the pipes as Gaurav suggested doesn't work as the backslashes appear in the output, which is wrong.

Eventually I got so fed up with Kramdown that I shifted to Redcarpet instead. Now everything works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

How about escaping them?

http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#automatic-and-manual-escaping

So in your case, it would probably be: `"Aadit M Shah \| Standardizing Harmony Classes"`!

Hope this helps!

Comment: I thought about that before. However as my question states: `There are lots of places where I have pipes and I don't wish to change them.` My reasoning is that my markdown is correct and that I don't need to change it. The problem is with Kramdown and I don't wish to modify my markdown just to work around an inane bug like this.

Comment: It isn't really a bug, it is what they provide as a feature -> http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#tables

Comment: It is a bug when __pipes inside a link text literal__ are treated as table cell separators.

Comment: Escaping the pipes doesn't work. The backslash is not removed from the output. I solved the problem by shifting from Kramdown to Redcarpet.

Answer (score 1):

Another late answer to the party.
To completely disable tables in kramdown, I ended up forking it and disabling tables in their source; it's a [1 line change](https://github.com/Raekye/kramdown/commit/fef86182716fe38eff69a2c1aa915d620f2476ec).

First, clone [kramdown](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown).
Then, in [`lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb`](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/lib/kramdown/parser/kramdown.rb) simply remove `:table` from the array `@block_parsers`.

You can easily update your kramdown with `git pull origin master`.

---

If you're using kramdown as a bundler gem, e.g. with the blogging tool jekyll, run `rake dev:gemspec` (to generate `kramdown.gemspec`) in the directory you cloned kramdown.
Then, in your `Gemfile` add:

```
gem 'kramdown', path: '/path/to/kramdown/folder'
```

where `/path/to/kramdown/folder` is the repository you cloned/directory containing `kramdown.gemspec`.
Finally, run `bundle install`.

---

If you're using the kramdown binary, I believe you can build it with `rake dev:gem` and it will be in a (newly created) `pkg/` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late to the party, but ran into this as well:

Kramdown supports multiple parsers, among which: `:Kramdown`, but also `:markdown` `:GFM` (Github Flavoured) and `:HTML`.

`:markdown` comes without table parsing and would've solved your problem as well. Initialize it as follows:

```
 Kramdown::Document.new(string, input: :markdown)
```